# How do i use paypal rest sdk with loopback

Tags: express, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to use paypal rest sdk with loopback. I want to know how to use it as middleware? I read the documentation and it talks about initial, final phases. Where do i need to register my paypal sdk and how? In my server.js file, I have imported it

```
var paypal  = require('paypal-rest-sdk')
```

what other steps, I should take? This is my middleware.json file?

```
{
  "initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
  },
  "initial": {
    "compression": {},
    "cors": {
      "params": {
        "origin": true,
        "credentials": true,
        "maxAge": 86400
      }
    },
    "helmet#xssFilter": {},
    "helmet#frameguard": {
      "params": [
        "deny"
      ]
    },
    "helmet#hsts": {
      "params": {
        "maxAge": 0,
        "includeSubdomains": true
      }
    },
    "helmet#hidePoweredBy": {},
    "helmet#ieNoOpen": {},
    "helmet#noSniff": {},
    "helmet#noCache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "session": {},
  "auth": {},
  "parse": {"body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}},
  "routes": {
    "loopback#rest": {
      "paths": [
        "${restApiRoot}"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": {},
  "final": {
    "loopback#urlNotFound": {}
  },
  "final:after": {
    "strong-error-handler": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, There was nothing more to it. I just imported it in model json file and it worked.

models/meetup.js

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk')
```